# Stringstream to string logic C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class CombatLine{   
    std::stringstream Line;    
    std::vector<std::string> TokenLine;  
    void SetLine(std::string s){   
        Line<<s;   
    }    
public:   
void SetTokenLine(){   
    int i=0;    
    while(i<5){   
        Line>>TokenLine[i];   
        i++;}      
    TokenLine.resize(i);   
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)   
        cout<<TokenLine[j];}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;   

int main () {   
    CombatLine Line1;   
    Line1.SetLine("[Combat] A bird attacks -Anthrax- and misses (dodge).");   
    Line1.SetTokenLine();   
}
```

This builds but I get this runtime error, `/cygdrive/C/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9.1/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh: line 33: 4500 Segmentation fault     <core dumped> sh "$<SHFILE>"`

I know it has to do with how I am manipulating strings & streams in the SetTokenFile, but I can't seem to pinpoint what.

This is a small piece to a larger project. Overall I am going to parse a dynamic text file, and later do comparisons on the entire file's contents.

Comment: **Please** use markdown codeblocks instead of HTML when formatting code; otherwise things like every `<` in your code block get removed (not to mention invalid HTML is generated). (Also, **using namespace std;** needs to die a horrendous death)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write directly into `TokenLine[i]` since it's initialized as an empty `vector` in your `CombatLine` constructor.  You won't need the `resize` if you build the vector up as you read each line.

Try this:

```
void SetTokenLine(){   
    int i=0;    
    string nextLine;
    while(i<5){   
        Line>>nextLine;
        TokenLine.push_back(nextLine);
        i++;}      
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)   
        cout<<TokenLine[j];}
```

Alternatively, you could preallocate 5 entries in the `vector` in the default `CombatLine` constructor, though this is brittle if the number of tokens you want to process changes.  With the below, you can write direct from the `stringstream` into `TokenLine[i]` if 0 <= i <= 4.

```
CombatLine::CombatLine() : TokenLine(5)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize TokenLine first, and THEN write into the contents, or a better habit is to use push_back, which will resize if necessary.